# How to turn three individual tuples into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have the following tuples with data:

```
      import pandas as pd

      tuple_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
      tuple_2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
      tuple_3 = [10,20,30,40,50]
```

I would like to build a dataframe containing these three tuples as columns of the dataframe.

When I do, with just a tuple is working:

```
      df = pd.DataFrame(data=tuple_1, columns=['Tuple 1'])
      print(df)


      Tuple 1
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
```

However, when I tried to do for the three tuples occurs the error:

```
       df = pd.DataFrame(data=[tuple_1, tuple_2, tuple_3], columns=['Tuple 1', 'Tuple 2', 'Tuple 3'])
```

ValueError: 3 columns passed, passed data had 5 columns

The desired output is:

```
       Tuple 1    Tuple 2   Tuple 3
         1          a         10
         2          b         20
         3          c         30
         4          d         40
         5          e         50
```

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/pandas/example/6134/create-a-dataframe-from-a-dictionary-of-lists

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks for sharing the link!

Solution:

df = pd.DataFrame({'tuple_1' : tuple_1, 'tuple_2' : tuple_2, 'tuple_3': tuple_3})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Tuple 1': tuple_1, 'Tuple 2': tuple_2, 'Tuple 3': tuple_3})
```

*NB. Your "tuples" are actually lists*

You could also fix your approach using `zip` to transpose the data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(*[tuple_1, tuple_2, tuple_3]), columns=['Tuple 1', 'Tuple 2', 'Tuple 3'])
```

Output:

```
   Tuple 1 Tuple 2  Tuple 3
0        1       a       10
1        2       b       20
2        3       c       30
3        4       d       40
4        5       e       50
```